# Trying to differentiate between two simple clock divider circuits - VHDL

Tags: vhdl

I'm very new to VHDL and I'm trying to design a simple clock divider process, but I'm running into a strange disparity between two forms of a process that I can't tell apart logically. I'd really appreciate help with this! Sorry if I don't include enough context, I don't know yet what would be helpful for this sort of thing.

Form 1:

```
div_main : process(clk_in) is
variable count : integer := 0;
begin
    if (rising_edge(clk_in) and sw_in(3) = '1') then
        count := count + 1;
        if (count > div) then
            count := 0;
            tmpclk <= not tmpclk;
        end if;
    end if;
end process div_main;
```

Form 2:

```
div_main : process(clk_in) is
variable count : integer := 0;
begin
    if (rising_edge(clk_in) and sw_in(3) = '1') then
        count := count + 1;
    end if;
    if (count > div) then
        count := 0;
        tmpclk <= not tmpclk;
    end if;
end process div_main;
```

(The sw input is a form of clk enable)
(The clk_in is a 125MHZ pin output on the FPGA)

The first form works perfectly, but I'm having a ton of issues with the second. It's tmpclk output is nearly random. The only difference I can see is whether the conditional reset of count is evaluated on only rising edges or on both rising and falling edges, which I wouldn't think matters. I would really appreciate if someone could explain why they behave so differently!

Comment: Always use integers with range specified. It will optimise your code in case synthesiser is not smart enough.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I'm not surprised that the second form gives you issues. Let's look at the code line-by-line.

First, we have the process declaration:

```
div_main : process(clk_in) is
    variable count : integer := 0;
begin
```

This tells the synthesizer/simulator to "trigger" the process any time `clk_in` changes. It also declares a `count` variable used internally. Note that this *may* be problematic in a synthesized design due to the fact that `integer` is not derived from `std_logic` like the `signed` and `unsigned` types defined in `ieee.numeric_std` (basically `std_logic_vector` with extra operator overloads). I would recommend changing the declaration to something like this:

```
    variable count : unsigned(15 downto 0) := (others => '0'); -- Set the size to whatever you need
```

Next, we have a synchronous statement triggered on the rising edge of the clock, along with a condition. `count` is incremented on every rising edge as long as `sw_in(3)` is asserted.

```
    if (rising_edge(clk_in) and sw_in(3) = '1') then
        count := count + 1;
    end if;
```

The problem lies in your next statement, which is a condition that is evaluated on *both* clock edges (no `rising_edge(clk_in)` if in if statement). Since the two if statements are *not* mutually exclusive, it is possible that `count` will be assigned twice in the same clock cycle.

```
    if (count > div) then
        count := 0;
        tmpclk <= not tmpclk;
    end if;
end process div_main;
```

If `count` were a signal, you *might* get more predictable behavior, but with a variable, it's difficult to say what will happen here. [This article](https://www.nandland.com/vhdl/tips/variable-vs-signal.html), which provides an excellent bit of insight into the difference between signals and variables.

> The most important thing to understand (and the largest source of confusion) is that *variables immediately take the value of their assignment*, whereas signals depend on if the signal is used in combinational or sequential code.

To put it another way, a simulator may be able to assign the variable twice in the same process, but this would be extremely problematic to implement in hardware. You are essentially shorting two outputs together, which is certainly not what you want.

---

While the first form is better, you will still encounter a similar issue if you try to implement it in hardware. Here is an implementation that should work in hardware, though it may still be better to use a signal instead of a variable for your counter.

```
div_main : process(clk_in) is
    variable count : unsigned(15 downto 0) := (others => '0');
begin
    if rising_edge(clk_in) and sw_in(3) = '1') then
        -- Note that count is only assigned once per rising edge of clk_in
        if (count > div) then
            count := (other => '0');
            tmpclk <= not tmpclk;
        else
            count := count + 1;
        end if;
    end if;
end process div_main;
```

Comment: Thanks, this definitely helped! As a followup, does the statement about assigned it twice in one clock cycle apply to any clk source? It is my understanding that the process statement is evaluated in full twice per cycle of clk_in (rising and falling edges) so I'm still a bit unsure how it interferes, seeing as resetting count to 0 on the rising edge makes the condition false.

Comment: @EvanBattaglia You have to remember that VHDL (unlike a programming language) is not inherently sequential. The nested if-else statement implements a multiplexer that would then be connected to `count` register. The fact that `count` is a register (as opposed to a latch or combinatorial output) depends entirely on the surrounding code, which in this case causes it to only be updated on a rising edge of `clk_in`.

Comment: -1 Warning against a use of integers would have been valid 20 years ago, these days it's just a sign that you no longer kept up with contemporary designs. Integers simulate faster, read more naturally and synthesize perfectly fine.

Comment: Same for variables, they are far superior to the use of signals. Re-assigning a variable multiple times works fine in hardware, it's called a combinatorial path. The whole answer reads as something that follows dogmatic rules that haven't been valid for decades.

Comment: @DonFusili I don't see how the OP's code implements a combinatorial path. Also, where would you suggest I look for the newer conventions.

Comment: @CalebReister OP's code wouldn't synthesize, but not because he assigns count two times in the same clock cycle, that's perfectly fine. Your code implements a different logic than a correction of OP's code would. No idea where you'd find the 'new conventions' because there's simply less needs for conventions HDL usage these days.

Comment: Anyway, your code would synthesize latches. It's a bad answer all around really.

Comment: Variables and integers are used by designers who know how to use it and where to use as they are extremely useful at times. There are no issues with using both. By the way disagree with Don saying this will infer latches. There are no latches here.

Comment: @Evan your code will infer a combinational logic for second if block which has inputs -- clock, count and div and output tmp. In fact its a combinatorial loop cz output tmp depends on itself in a loop (not gate). Its like an inverters output is tied to its input. Synthesiser will throw warnings errors for it. Write all synchronous logic inside the clock edge. Interesting thing is that you also have something called synthesis simulation mismatch here. What you simulate is not what synthesiser will actually give you cz of senstivity list being incomplete

Comment: Thanks everyone, I really appreciate the help. Unfortunately, I feel like I'm missing a fair amount of foundational understanding regarding VHDL synthesis.  I have basic knowledge about digital logic elements, but I haven't really found any material even close to my level that talks about this kind of stuff 9. How did you guys learn this? Do you have any references that you would suggest?

Comment: No Books cover everything. We all learnt with trial and error just like you.. And got some experience.. . Code simulate n synthesis whenever you wonder - what happens if i do like this..

Comment: I have a suggestion of books anyway - VHDL books by Roth/Douglas and Synthesis VHDL Primer by J. Bhasker